# Show code coverage in python using green

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-green

I am using green for my python project. I have a problem on knowing which part of the code that still uncovered with the unit test. When I run the green using `green -vvv --run-coverage`, on the result, it only shows the percentage of the covered code. How could I know which part of the code that were not covered? Is there any additional syntax that I can use in order to show the uncovered code?

Answer (score 2):

*Sorry for the delay! I didn't see this question come in!*

Coverage 4.1 changed default internal behavior which disabled the missing line output in coverage through Green.  This was fixed in Green 2.5.3.

So either use Coverage < 4.1 or Green >= 2.5.3 and you should get the missing lines output.